# launch other "npm run" inside of a nodejs script

Tags: node.js, npm, fork

So I have a script called script.js,

during it I want to fork the process to start 2 other process who do "npm run something" and "ng serve",

any idea how to do it?

```
let child1 = fork("npm run something")
let child2 = fork("ng serve")
...

await waitForLog(child1, "finish") 
await waitForLog(child2, "deploy") 

...
```

Iv'e try fork("npm run something"), but it return me "module not found" error.

In bonus, I can't use any extra lib (other than childprocess)

Comment: Try concurrently package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently#Programmatic%20Usage

Comment: @Dilshan I can't use extra lib